# JSON:TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, iteration

I'm trying to get Total Confirmed Cases for Global from [here](https://api.covid19api.com/summary) , but i get `TypeError: string indices must be integers` when i try to run this function:

```
def getstats():
    api_url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.covid19api.com/summary')
    data = json.load(api_url)
    for item in data["Global"]:
        print(item["TotalConfirmed"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over items in `data["Global"]` returns keys as strings.

```py
print(*(i for i in data["Global"]))
```

```
NewConfirmed TotalConfirmed NewDeaths TotalDeaths NewRecovered TotalRecovered
```

What you're trying to do is get the value of an internal dictionary

```py
print(data["Global"]["TotalConfirmed"])
```

```
2807945
```

Answer (score 0):

The `item` is a `String` under the `Global` key. Use `print(item)` to see the string. You need to parse that string further to get the `TotalConfirmed` value.